# Why combining two quadratic equations of a circle and a parabola creates extra solutions for $x$

Tags: analytic-geometry, quadratics

We have a parabola and a circle with the following equations and their graph placed at the end of my question.

Parabola: $y^2 = 4x -4$

Circle: $(x-2)^2 + y^2 = 9$

My goal was to calculate their intersection points so I substituted $y^2$ from the parabola equation into the circle equation and I got

$(x-2)^2 + (4x-4)=9 \implies x^2 - 4x + 4 + (4x - 4) = 9 \implies x^2 = 9 \implies x = \pm3$

$x=3$ is the only correct solution but why is $x=-3$ produced as an extra invalid solution?

What is the exact mathematical explanation behind this? Why substituting one equation into the other has produced extra answers?

[image]

### update

When I calculate $x$ from the parabola equation and substitute it in the circle equation, I don't get any extra answers for $y$:

$y^2=4x-4 \implies y^2 +4 = 4x \implies x = \frac{y^2}{4} + 1$

$(x-2)^2 +(4x-4)=9 \implies ((\frac{y^2}{4} + 1) - 2)^2 + (4x - 4)=9 \implies y^4 +8y - 128 = 0 \implies y^2=8,-16$

$y^2 = -16$ cannot be true so $y^2 = 8 \implies y=\pm 2\sqrt{2}$ and these are correct answers for $y$.

### 2nd update

I made a mistake in the calculation in the previous update although the final solutions where correct. I write the correct calculation:

$(x-2)^2 +y^2=9 \implies 
((\frac{y^2}{4} + 1) - 2)^2 + y^2=9 \implies 
(\frac{y^2}{4} - 1)^2 + y^2=9 \implies 
(\frac{y^4}{16} - \frac{y^2}{2} + 1) + y^2=9 \implies 
\frac{y^4}{16} + \frac{y^2}{2} + 1=9 \implies 
(\frac{y^2}{4} +  1)^2=9 \implies 
(\frac{y^2}{4} +  1)=\pm3 \implies
\frac{y^2}{4} =2,-4 \implies
y^2=8,-16$

Comment: $x=-3, y= \pm4i$ are perfectly valid solutions.

Comment: Algebraically, a system involving a degree-$m$ polynomial equation and a degree-$n$ polynomial equation has $m\times n$ roots (over the complex numbers). Whether these roots have geometric relevance (or are even *real* values) is a separate consideration about which the algebra itself doesn't know or care. (It's worth noting that a circle and parabola *can* actually meet in up to four ($=2\times2$) real points.)

Comment: @Blue so I can conclude that $x=-3$ is a valid answer but if we consider complex numbers. Is it correct to say that every real answer for $(x,y)$ must satisfy in both equations?

Comment: @Blue there is no need for geometric relevance. If the answers we get satisfy in the equation in the real number system, then they are automatically on the parabola and circle.

Comment: Right: $x=-3$ is "algebraically valid" here, even though it's "geometrically extraneous". (That said, there are often ways to attach geometric significance to non-real solutions, but that's a whole other discussion.) I can't say that, in general, every result that emerges from a solving system must satisfy the original equations. It's entirely possible that the solution process itself introduced algebraically extraneous results. (One might see this, say, when squaring both sides of an equation.) So, it's important to verify that candidate solutions actually do the job intended.

Comment: @Blue you are correct. For example when we square both sides of an equation, we might get extraneous answers. But here I did not square or take root. I want to know the conditions where in such equations extraneous (imaginary) answers will be produced or might be produced and we have to be careful and check the answers such as when we square both sides

Comment: @OmidSadeghi: *Always* check. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that we are working on the real number system and not consider complex numbers but I think my reasoning works in complex numbers too. We want to solve a system of equations containing two equations. I move all terms of each equation to one side and name them $A(x,y)$ and $B(x,y)$

$\begin{cases}
      A(x,y)=y^2 -4x +4=0\\
      B(x,y)=y^2 +(x-2)^2-9=0\\
    \end{cases}$

We want to find tuples like $(x', y')$ such that $A(x',y')=0$ and $B(x',y')=0$ simultaneously.

If we calculate $y^2$ from $A(x,y)=0$ and substitute it into $B(x,y)$ we arrive at a third equation $C(x)=0$

$C(x) = 4x-4 +(x-2)^2-9 = 0 \implies C(x) = x^2 -9=0$

And when we solve $C(x) = 0$ we get $x^2=9 \implies x=\pm 3$ but any point $(-3,y)$ with $y\in\mathbb{R}$ does not satisfy $\begin{cases}
      A(x,y)=0\\
      B(x,y)=0\\     
    \end{cases}$
and the solving procedure has produced extraneous solutions. The reason is this the line of reasoning is not reversible.

$\begin{cases}
      A(x,y)=0\\
      B(x,y)=0\\     
    \end{cases} \overset{1}{\implies} C(x)=0 \overset{2}{\iff} x=\pm 3$

The $\overset{1}{\implies}$ is not reversible. In this case when there exists $(x_0,y_0)$ as a solution to the system we will have:

$\begin{cases}
      A(x_0,y_0)=0\\
      B(x_0,y_0)=0\\     
    \end{cases} \overset{3}\implies C(x_0)=0 \overset{4}\iff x_0=\pm 3$

but if there exits $(x_1,y_1)$ as a solution to $C(x) = 0$ we will have

$C(x_1)=0 \;\not\!\!\!\implies \begin{cases}
      A(x_1,y_1)=0\\
      B(x_1,y_1)=0\\     
    \end{cases}$

When we combine the equations we loose information and cannot retrive the system $\begin{cases}
      A(x_1,y_1)=0\\
      B(x_1,y_1)=0\\     
    \end{cases}$ from $C(x)=0$
so every solution to the system is a solution to $C(x)=0$ but we cannot say every solution to $C(x)=0$ must be a solution to the system and extraneous solutions might have been produced.

Comment: studying [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3792636/extraneous-solution-from-substituting-in-equations) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186022/what-causes-the-extraneous-root-when-intersecting-parabola-y2-4ax-with-circle) which are very related helped me in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Total there are 4 roots, two real roots you have given are ok.
The remaining two with $x=-3$ substitution give imaginary $ y= \pm 4i$ and they should be discarded as extraneous, spurious etc. when looking for real solutions.

The above  $x,y$ parts of a point should both be real for a full real solution.

$(x,y)= (-3,4i)$ are admissible as complex roots.

Had you computed $y$ values instead of $x,$ you would have noticed different imaginary values , with different signs as above.

Answer (score 1):

When you are searching for intersection of two figures the intersection dot must satisfy parabola equation which indicates that

$$ y^2 = 4x - 4$$

Which means that

$$ 4x - 4 \geq 0$$
$$ x \geq 1 $$

The last inequality will exclude $x = -3$ solution.

Comment: I know that $x=-3$ is the wrong answer because $x$ must be greater than one. My question is why this wrong extraneous solution is produced when we solve the equation by substituting one in the other?

Comment: The other solution is a solution, it just produces an imaginary value for $y$, which is why you do not see it on the Cartesian plane.

Comment: @OmidSadeghi because you are looking for real solutions. There are no “wrong solutions”.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x-2)^2 + y^2 = 9 \tag{A}$$
requires that $x \in [-1,5]$ and $y \in [-3,3]$.

$$y^2 = 4x-4 \tag{B}$$ requires that $x \in [1, \infty)$.

So, for $x$ to satisfy both (A) and (B), we must have
$x \in  [1, \infty) \cap [-1,5] =  [1,5]$.

Hence $x=-3$ will be an extraneous root.

Answer (score 0):

A standard Cartesian graph deals only with real numbers "plotted against" real numbers, so in looking at the intersections of two curves in such a graph, one may not be "getting the whole story."   Two distinct quadratic curves will have *four* intersections; since one of these (the circle) is bounded, all of the intersection points will be at finite distances from the origin.

If we use the curve equations with complex numbers $ \ x \ = \ a + bi \ $ and $ \ y \ = \ c + di \ \ , $ (with $ \ a \ , \ b \ , \ c \ , \ d \ $ **real**), they  become
$$ (x-2)^2 \ + \ y^2 \ \ = \ \ 9 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ ( \ [a - 2] + bi \ )^2 \ + \ ( \ c \ + \ di \ )^2 \ \ = \ \ 9 $$
$$ \rightarrow \ \ [ \ (a^2 - 4a - b^2 + 4) \ + \ (2a  - 4 )·b·i \ ]   \ + \ [ \ (c^2 - d^2) \ + \ 2cd·i \ ] \ \ = \ \ 9 \ + \ 0·i  \ \ ; $$
$$ y^2 \ \ = \ \ 4x \ - \ 4 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ (c + di)^2 \ \ = \ \ 4·(a + bi) \ - \ 4 \ \  = \ \ (4a - 4) \ + \ 4bi \ \ . $$

The calculation without the imaginary parts ($ \ b \ = \ d \ = \ 0 \ $) is the one you made (the one we learn to make in "standard" analytic geometry), giving $ \ \ a^2 \ = \ 9 \ \ , \ \ c^2 \ = \ 4·a - 4   \ \ . $   We take $ \ a \ = \ +3 \ \ , $ $ c^2 \ = \ 4·(+3) - 4 \ = \ 8 \ \ , $ and "discard"   $ \ a \ = \ -3 \ $ , since it leads to $ \ c^2 \ = \ 4·(+3) - 4 \ = \ -16 \ \ $ , which is *not permissible* since $ \ c \ $ is taken to be a real number.  Your graph then represents *real part* $ \ c \ $ for $ \ y \ $ as a function of *real part* $ \ a \ \   $ for $ \ x \ \ . $

But a "graph" using complex numbers needs to be made in $ \ \mathbb{C}^2 \ \ , $ which can be interpreted in $ \ \mathbb{R}^4 \ \ , $ making it challenging to visualize, as the "curves" are then treated as four-dimensional.  The  intersections we "rejected" occur in those extended parts of the curves.  If we return to the curve equations and work with the two-dimensional "slice" that "graphs" the *imaginary* part $ \ d \ $ of $ \ y \ $ against the real part $ \ a \ $ of $ \ x \ \ $ (so $ \ b \ = \ c = \ 0 \ $ ) , we obtain
$$ ( \ [a - 2] + 0·i \ )^2 \ + \ ( \  0 + di \ )^2 \ \ = \ \ 9 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ (a - 2)^2 \ -  \ d^2 \ \ = \ \ 9 \ \ ; $$
$$ (0 + di)^2 \ \ = \ \ 4·(a + 0·i) \ - \ 4 \ \  \rightarrow \ \ -d^2 \ \ = \ 4a \ - \ 4  \ \ . $$

This produces $ \ a^2 \ = \ 9 \ \ , \ \ -d^2 \ = \ 4a - 4 \ \ , $ but using $ \ a \ = \ +3 \ $ will give us $ \ -d^2 \ = \ 8 \ \ , $ which we now "reject" because $ \ d \ $ is a real number; here, we take $ \ a \ = \ -3 \ \Rightarrow \ -d^2 \ = \ -16 \ \Rightarrow \ d \ = \ \pm 4 \ \ . $  As we see on the graph of $ \ d \ $ *versus* $ \ a \ $ below, we have found that a *hyperbolic* part of $ \ (x-2)^2   +   y^2 \   =   \ 9 \ $ intersects a parabolic part of $ \ y^2 \ \ = \ \ 4x \ - \ 4 \ $ at the points $ \ (-3 \ , \ \pm   4i) \ \ , $ as mentioned by **Narasimham**.

[image]

We have accounted then for the four intersections of the two curves, two of which are "invisible" on a "standard" graph in $ \ \mathbb{R}^2 \ \ . $  No other intersections appear on other "slices":  for instance, the imaginary part $ \ d \ $ *versus* imaginary part $ \ b \ $ equations are
$$ ( \ [0 - 2] + b·i \ )^2 \ + \ ( \  0 + di \ )^2 \ \ = \ \ 9 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ 4 \ - \ b^2 \ -  \ d^2 \ \ = \ \ 9 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ b^2 \ + \ d^2 \ \ = \ \ -5 \ \ ; $$
$$ (0 + di)^2 \ \ = \ \ 4·(0 + b·i) \ - \ 4 \ \  \rightarrow \ \ -d^2 \ \ = \ 4bi \ - \ 4  \ \ , $$
which do not produce real solutions for $ \ b \ $ and $ \ d \ \ . $

Comment: Thanks. you said two distinct quadratic will have four intersections. Do you mean in complex numbers? Is it always true in complex numbers? Is it possible that combining equations lead to extraneous solutions in complex numbers or remove some solutions in complex numbers?

Comment: Yes, Bezout's Theorem [see, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem ] tells us that the number of intersections will (generally) equal the product of the degrees of the polynomials (in this problem, $ \ 2·2 \ \ . $  I hedged a little bit in my answer because the space that it applies in is the product of two complex projective planes, which include the "point at infinity".  Here, though, all of the intersections have pairs of complex-number coordinates that are finite. [continued]

Comment: There will not be "extraneous solutions" because intersections at infinity also get counted; intersections can also have multiplicities in the count.  So solutions don't "disappear" when working in that space.  It should be said that this concept developed in order to be able to make generalizations about how algebraic equations can be solved, just as the idea of complex numbers (or even irrational and negative numbers) broadened our understanding of solving polynomial equations.